# Angular2 Child component Display but not parent List using Router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I am using Router in Angular2 (beta 17. Can't make the RCs work with rails so far).
It worked all ok until I simply set a components inside one the component used as path.

Once I did this, the Route would display only the Child component and not the parent list that supposed to be there anymore.

This is driving me crazy...

So router configs:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '',
    name: 'Home',
    component: MainComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/demo-component/:id',
    name: 'Demo Component Details',
    component: DemoComponentDetail
  },
])
```

Main Component:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<filter></filter>
<div *ngFor="let d of demo_components">
<p>{{ d.Name }}</p>
</div>
```

Main component ts:

```
    import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {Router} from 'angular2/router'
import {DemoComponentService} from '../shared/demo-component.service'
import {FilterComponent} from '../filters/filter.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  templateUrl: '/app/demo-components/main.component.html',
  directives: [ FilterComponent ]
})

export class MainComponent{
  demo_components: any[]
  constructor(private router:Router, private service: DemoComponentService){
    this.demo_components = this.service.getAllDemoComponents();
  }
```

This is where I don't understand:
If I remove the directive for the child component, my list works well (but I am loosing the filter component of course).
But if I leave the directive as it is, then my List (*ngFor) does not display anymore, only the filter child component displays...

What is happening ?! Can you not have a simple component inside a parent one used by a Route ?

Comment: What archaic Angular2 version are you using? ;-)

Comment: The 2.0.0-beta.17. Unfortunately that is the only one I managed to get working with my Rails project. :'(

Comment: Rather pointless using such an old version. I can't imagine that a newer version doesn't work with Rails. It would be better you asked about problem that prevent you from using the most recent version.